# Django form as GET - Retrieving data from existing tables

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

how to write the views.py by GET request if I got some value from user

```
from django import forms
accountId = forms.DecimalField(label='account number', max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control',
}))
```

The accountId is a PK of table "account".
I have another table called "person" in the account models I have 
person_Id  - Which is a foreign key

I need to make a get request

- first, make sure that the accountID is valid and existing in the table "account"
- seconde, retrieve the data from the tables and display them to the user on the screen - localhost:8000/polls/....

means, I got the "accountId" and verified that it is valid, and now look for the row in the SQL table that refers to this accountId number and retrieve the data from other fields(accountNo, openDate, typeA=(some enum)),
In addition, access the "person" table and also retrieve the data(Pname, PlastName, Ptel) by the accountId provided from this table.

all the tutorials were about POST
How do I perform this action what I need to write in the views.py? (and what I need to write in the xx.html to view the user's data after he has entered the AccountIdshould)
if somebody can write it, it will help

Comment: You could validate the get query params by just passing them as data - `form = YourForm(data=request.GET)`, `form.is_valid()`. Or if you want to validate it yourself, just access the dict from the request.GET.

Comment: @mfrackowiak thanks and after I did it , How do I retrieve data from tables by the request.get ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a form for this at all.